# Failed to start session after upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS before upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using the program-updater.
Now when the installation was done, I restarted my PC.
Now it says that it failed to start the session after I try logging in.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try the following (an attempt to reset your Unity configuration):

```
mv ~/.config/unity ~/.config/unity.bak
```

If that does not work, feel free to revert/undo the changes like so:

```
rm -r ~/.config/unity
mv ~/.config/unity.bak ~/.config/unity
```

Alternatively, it would be great if you could provide a more detailed description, perhaps with some output from `/var/log/syslog`.